# Repost or flag my own question for migration?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, migration

I posted a question in which a commenter suggested that I migrate my post. It looks like the only way to do this is to flag as other/needs mod attention.

Should I do this, or just repost? That is, which is worse, using a moderator's time or creating a duplicate question? Does this depend on how much progress has been made on the question, or should it always be one or the other?

Comment: Use the "Other" flag asking a moderator to migrate the question to the correct site.  As long as the question isn't older than 60 days, we should be able to migrate it.

Comment: Thanks. If you would be kind enough to do that, here's the question http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112387/one-step-ahead-stochastic-volatility-for-5-minute-vwap-prices

Comment: Where do you want that question moved?  If you want it moved from Stats, then you have to flag that there.  I'm a mod on SO and don't have the ability to move questions from other sites.

Answer (score 11):

You have two options depending on the situation.

1. If the question has no answers or only one answer that doesn't have upvotes then it might be easier to delete and repost.
2. If the question has multiple answers or one answer with upvotes then you can't delete so migration is your only option.

Reposting *might* be a better option as you might ask a better question the second time around. If you can't delete your initial question be sure to flag it for closure though - cross posting is not welcome.