# What if after posting a question here I realise it belongs to some other SE site!

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration

So I happened to ask a database question today and then realized what I asked is probably a legacy technique being used in the industry and people on SO might not respond to it quickly, however if I moved the same to DBA network site, I might get some comments or answers!

Then I ended up flagging my own question for migration which is weird I know! Not that I am not aware that on SE network, what kind of questions should be posted where but specifically in this field - database, one naturally comes to SO and then recalls that it could have been on DBA as well.

I have personally flagged some questions from other users for migration, but shouldn't there be a way of doing it by yourself for OP??

Comment: If users could manually migrate their own questions then they might start trying to get around site-specific question bans by writing up the question somewhere else and then migrating it afterwards. Just food for thought...

Comment: In general, I don't think the various communities want to give the users the ability to directly move questions as it could result in someone just moving a post from 1 site to another until they get an answer.  But you have a method on your own - the delete button and posting it on the new site.

Comment: @JonK someone might try, but it won't succeed, no one (not even mods) can move a question to a site where the OP has a question ban.

Comment: @psubsee2003 It's not that they can or can't succeed, more that they're more likely to *try*, which just ends up causing work for other people to either migrate it or (more likely) close it.

Comment: see also: [Repost or flag my own question for migration?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269192/repost-or-flag-my-own-question-for-migration)

Comment: @gnat There is no answer to that question!

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277952/839601

Comment: @Neels: It sure looks like that question has an answer, since August.  It isn't accepted, but big deal, the votes of the community count for more than the checkmark anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If no one has answered the question yet, there's nothing wrong with deleting it on the not-quite-right site and re-posting it on the more suitable site.<sup>1, 4</sup>

If there are (upvoted) answers, then generally the Asker will need to vote to migrate the question (if the target is one of the default migration choices) *and* get four other people to agree<sup>2</sup>.

[George Stocker](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/16587) suggests that a custom Moderator flag requesting the migration is your best option. There's no guarantee that a Moderator will agree with you, however, especially if the question is not completely off-topic at the original site and/or is not a good migration candidate<sup>3</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> If you're worried about losing all of the information/formatting in the question, just open the edit window and copy, then paste in the new site.
<sup>2</sup> Agree to close, that is. The choice to migrate does not need to be unanimous.
<sup>3</sup> The Golden Rule of Migrations: *Don't migrate crap.*
<sup>4</sup> Don't make this a habit, though. If you're regularly misposting questions and deleting them, you may find yourself throttled from asking questions at all.

Comment: The best thing to do would be to flag it for migration.  deleting/reposting may have unintended side effects if the question has negative votes for deletion. Like a user getting question banned, for example.

Comment: @George: Presumably this isn't something that happens regularly enough to run up against any post-throttling. If someone regularly posts off-topic questions on one site, then deletes them to post on another site, I think they should get their lumps.

Comment: ...but I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Really well written answer.  You're right that even if they flag it for migration, we may not migrate it. If we don't think it has a reasonable chance of surviving a migration, we won't do it.

Comment: This question is being voted down to get closed!! Heck.. We have an answer to an issue which is being appreciated by the Mod too and yet there are people who want to close it because there is an unanswered duplicate on meta! Doesn't seem fair to me!

Comment: @Neels there is not a single downvote.  And yes it is getting voted to closed.  But the point of duplicates are not to draw and quarter users who post duplicates, it is to link questions that have the same topic so we don't have 2 posts with the same discussion.  Since this one has an answer and the other doesn't, it might be better to close that one as a dup of this one, but it's not the end of the world.

Comment: Not the end of the world but feels bad. :( And as you suggest, can't be done I guess because the other question was asked first! Hen came first or the egg kinda situation will get created in that case!